# OnItemClick in recyclerView, get data and start activity and display data

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I know how to get and show data in simple `ListView`'s `OnItemClick`, but no idea for `RecyclerView`.

I just want to take particular item name and image any pass it to next activity and display.

What i have done is:

**1) MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static ArrayList<DataModel> data;
    static View.OnClickListener myOnClickListener;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> removedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener(this);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        data = new ArrayList<DataModel>();
        for (int i = 0; i < MyData.nameArray.length; i++) {
            data.add(new DataModel(
                    MyData.nameArray[i],
                    MyData.versionArray[i],
                    MyData.id_[i],
                    MyData.drawableArray[i]
            ));
        }

        removedItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.add_item) {
            //check if any items to add
            if (removedItems.size() != 0) {
                addRemovedItemToList();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to add", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static class MyOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Context context;

        private MyOnClickListener(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            removeItem(v);
            onItemClick(v);
        }

        private void onItemClick(View v) {
            int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder
                    = recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedItemPosition);
            TextView textViewName
                    = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            ImageView image
                    = (ImageView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            String selectedName = (String) textViewName.getText();

            int selectedItemId = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < MyData.nameArray.length; i++) {
                if (selectedName.equals(MyData.nameArray[i])) {
                    selectedItemId = MyData.id_[i];
                }
            }

        }

        private void removeItem(View v) {
            int selectedItemPosition = recyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder
                    = recyclerView.findViewHolderForPosition(selectedItemPosition);
            TextView textViewName
                    = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            String selectedName = (String) textViewName.getText();
            int selectedItemId = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < MyData.nameArray.length; i++) {
                if (selectedName.equals(MyData.nameArray[i])) {
                    selectedItemId = MyData.id_[i];
                }
            }
            removedItems.add(selectedItemId);
            data.remove(selectedItemPosition);
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(selectedItemPosition);
        }
    }

    private void addRemovedItemToList() {
        int addItemAtListPosition = 3;
        data.add(addItemAtListPosition, new DataModel(
                MyData.nameArray[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.versionArray[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.id_[removedItems.get(0)],
                MyData.drawableArray[removedItems.get(0)]
        ));
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(addItemAtListPosition);
        removedItems.remove(0);
    }




}
```

**2) DataModel:**

```
public class DataModel {


    String name;
    String version;
    int id_;
    int image;

    public DataModel(String name, String version, int id_, int image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.id_ = id_;
        this.image=image;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id_;
    }
}
```

**3) Adapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<DataModel> dataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageViewIcon;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.textViewName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
            this.textViewVersion = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVersion);
            this.imageViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<DataModel> data) {
        this.dataSet = data;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.cards_layout, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.myOnClickListener);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

        TextView textViewName = holder.textViewName;
        TextView textViewVersion = holder.textViewVersion;
        ImageView imageView = holder.imageViewIcon;

        textViewName.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getName());
        textViewVersion.setText(dataSet.get(listPosition).getVersion());
        imageView.setImageResource(dataSet.get(listPosition).getImage());


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my `BaseViewHollder`:

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
}

public BaseViewHolder(View itemView, final ViewHolderClickListener listener) {
    super(itemView);
    if (listener != null) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onViewHolderClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }
}


public interface ViewHolderClickListener {
    void onViewHolderClick(View view, int position);
}
}
```

In your `Adapter`, you have to `extends` the `BaseViewHolder` from your `ViewHolder`. Then you can:

```
 @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(yourLayoutId, parent, false);
    // your viewHolderClickListener, you can set it in constructor
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, viewHolderClickListener);
    return vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a onClick for itemView in your MyViewHolder class. If you still need a code , just let me know .